# Can anyone explain output

Tags: c, macros, output, printf

```
#define power(a) #a
  int main()
  {
    printf("%d",*power(432));
     return 0;
  }
```

can anyone explain the o/p??
[the o/p is](http://ideone.com/7cromp)

52

Comment: What do you think it does? Have you made any effort understanding this code? It's trivial.

Comment: i m not able to understand what '*' does??

Comment: In that case you're in the most serious need of reading a basic C language tutorial. It's used for pointer dereferencing.

Comment: @akash in `power(432)` => `"432"` and `*"432"` => `"432"[0]` => `'4'` and because `%d` ascii value printed. Remember we do `char* ch = "432"` that means type of  a string is `"432"` is  `char*` so we can index using `[]`. as we can do `ch[]` Your **macro** convert macro function argument to string. because single `#` operator.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is equivalent to:

```
printf("%d",*"432");
```

which is equivalent to:

```
printf("%d", '4');
```

and the ASCII value of `'4'` is `52`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define power(a) #a   //# is a stringization operation in macro
  int main()
  {
    printf("%d",*power(432));
     return 0;
  }

Hence after calling power(432), macro will return it "432" and applying * on it gives first value which is nothing but 52 (48 + 4) for '4' .
```